# Go assignment involving pointers to custom types

Tags: go, pointers, variable-assignment, user-defined-types

I am using custom types and I have a problem when pointers are involved like below.

Code below is valid:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type deck []string

func newDeck(cards ...string) deck {
    return cards
}
```

Code below is valid too:

```
package main

func str(n []string) *[]string {
return &n
}
```

The below code instead is not valid. Why so? I have to write a type conversion like `return (*deck)(&cards)`

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type deck []string

func newDeck(cards ...string) *deck {
    return &cards // compiles with return (*deck)(&cards)
}
```

Comment: `*[]string` and `*deck` are [distinct types](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Type_definitions). You have to convert the former to the latter before returning: `return (*deck)(&cards)`. See https://go.dev/play/p/HexSf4__9V5

Comment: So you are saying `[]string`  and `deck`  are not distinct types but `*[]string` and `*deck` are?

Comment: Even though they have the same [_underlying type_](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Underlying_types), `[]string` and `deck` are distinct types; therefore, so are `*[]string` and `*deck`.

Comment: So why first example works because `cards` is type of `[]string` and I am returning `deck`. https://go.dev/play/p/y_oVb57CO5h

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rules about assignments (including returns) are defined in the [Go specs: Assignability](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Assignability). The one that is relevant to your case is:

> `V` and `T` have identical underlying types and at least one of V or T is not a named type.

And [Underlying types](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Underlying_types):

> If T is one of the predeclared boolean, numeric, or string types, **or a type literal**, the corresponding underlying type is T itself.

The first example compiles because `[]string` is an unnamed type literal with underlying type `[]string` (itself) and `deck` is a named type with underlying type `[]string` (by your type definition).

The second example does not compile because both `*[]string` and `*deck` are unnamed type literals with themselves as (different) underlying types.

To make the second example compile, you can't rely on a direct assignment, but, as you found out, use an explicit type conversion

```
return (*deck)(&cards)
```

And this conversion is valid due to the following [rule](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Conversions):

> ignoring struct tags (see below), `x`'s type and `T` are pointer types that are not named types, and their pointer base types are not type parameters but have identical underlying types.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that `*[]string` and `*deck` have different underlying types (even though `[]string` and `deck` have the same underlying type). That's what I was missing and couldn't find in the spec.